# extension method for utility class from external library

Tags: extension-methods, kotlin

I am using `FilenameUtils` from `apache commons`

I had such action in the code

```
val customPath = FilenameUtils.getPath(source) +
        DEFAULT_SEPARATOR + FilenameUtils.getBaseName(source)
val resultPath = FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem(customPath)
```

I decided to make it into the extension method. I moved it into the separate class.

```
object PluginExtensions {

    fun FilenameUtils.normalizeFilePath(source: String) : String {
        val customPath = FilenameUtils.getPath(source) +
                DEFAULT_SEPARATOR + FilenameUtils.getBaseName(source)
        return FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem(customPath)
    }

    fun File(name: String) : File = File(name).apply {
        createNewFile()
    }
}
```

However it is unable to find that new method in class where I am using it

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can use this extension method, you have to import it.

```
import PluginExtensions.normalizeFilePath
```

Your extension funcion is defined only for the PluginExtensions object. Anywhere outside of this object you need import to make extension visible. Alternative would be to define extension at the package level. This would make your extension visible for the whole package.

Take a look at the documentation for extensions. Specifically [Scope of Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#scope-of-extensions).

Comment: I would highlight that top-level extension functions are currently **the preferred way** of declaring them. I'm not sure that Object-level extensions are even supposed to work that way.

Comment: Related issue for autocompleting object extensions (currently "to be considered"): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15286#tab=History

Comment: I see. I felt that I need to import it somehow, however I did not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the function to the file where you are calling it. An extension function is not located in the class that you are extending. It is located at the place where you defined it.

Write this in the file where you are using the function:

```
import PluginExtensions.normalizeFilePath
```